# distinguishing json column of RowProxy in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql

For example, when I execute following code, resulting data type is `str`:

```
result = engine.execute('''
  SELECT CAST('{"foo": "bar"}' as JSON) as `json`
''')
row = result.fetchone()
json = row[0]
type(json)
```

An json column value having type of `str` is not so much meta-programming friendly.

#### Question

Is there any way to fetch information from the `result` (or, an instance of `ResultProxy`) what each column's type was?

#### env

- MySQL: 8.0.11
- SQLAlchemy: 1.3.0
- pymysql: 0.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least achieve it by explicitly [telling SQLAlchemy that the result is JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#specifying-result-column-behaviors):

```
from sqlalchemy.types import JSON

stmt = text('''SELECT CAST('{"foo": "bar"}' as JSON) as `json`''')
stmt = stmt.columns(json=JSON)

row = engine.execute(stmt).fetchone()
type(row.json)
```